# Multiprocessing extremely slow after fitting CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, countvectorizer

Inside a class I've made use of multiprocessing in order to be able to use all cores for a specific method. This worked perfectly, until I added a (sklearn) CountVectorizer to the class. Somehow, after the CountVectorizer is fitted, the async_method becomes extremely slow. I have no idea what is causing this issue, especially since there is no relation between the CountVectorizer and the async_method. I wrote a small piece of reproducible code demonstrating the issue:

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from datetime import datetime


class ProblemClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cv = CountVectorizer()

    def random_function(self, max_wait):
        some_number = random.randint(0, max_wait)
        return some_number

    def async_method(self, some_list):
        cpu_count = mp.cpu_count()
        with mp.Pool(cpu_count - 1) as pool:
            result = [pool.apply_async(self.random_function, args=[row]) for row in some_list]
            result = [r.get() for r in result]
        return result

def timeit(func, *args):
    start = datetime.now()
    result = func(*args)
    stop = datetime.now()
    print(f"Time it took {stop-start}")
    return stop-start

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Before fitting countvectorizer
    pc = ProblemClass()
    some_list = random.choices(range(10), k=200)
    time_orig = timeit(pc.async_method, some_list)

    # This is fast, now look what happens when the countvectorizer is fitted
    X = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=random.randint(2, 10))) for _ in range(10000)]
    pc.cv.fit(X)
    time_after = timeit(pc.async_method, some_list)

    print(f"Why does is take {time_after/time_orig} times longer after fittin a CountVectorizer?")
```

Output:

> Time it took 0:00:00.051204 
>   Time it took 0:00:04.937169 
> Why does is 
>   now take 96.42154909772674 times longer?

It takes about 100 times as long to complete after fitting the CountVectorizer. Any ideas about what might be causing this?

Of course I can put either the async_method or the CountVectorizer in a separate class, but I want to understand what is going on here.